# D3 charts and JSON

Tags: json, d3.js

Hi I created one d3 stacked horizontal chart with data given as an array in the HTML itself. Now I want to remove the data from code and place it as a separate JSON file. When I tried its giving me error which am not able to solve. Here is my previous code which was working and the latest code

```
dataset = [{
        data: [{
            Region: 'N',
            count: 500
        }, {
            Region: 'W',
            count: 200
        }, {    
            Region: 'C',
            count: 300
        }, {
            Region: 'E',
            count: 150
        }],
        name: 'Average Order Management Time'
    }, {
        data: [{
            Region: 'N',
            count: 500
        }, {
            Region: 'W',
            count: 400
        }, {
            Region: 'C',
            count: 150
        },    {
            Region: 'E',
            count: 255
        }],     
        name: 'Average Enrichment Time'
   }];

dataset = dataset.map(function (d) {
               //code goes here
          });
```

now I created a separated json file and modified the code as below.

```
d3.csv("AvgHori.json", function(error, data){
   //code goes here
}),
```

Chart is not appearing and when I debugged it gave me this error.

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference 
What is this? Why the cart is not taking my JSON file

Comment: can you put the code in Fiddle

Comment: Gilsha's answer is right -- you should be using the `d3.json` method to parse json. Also make sure you have valid json format for your file.

Answer (score 1):

D3 parses json files using d3.json method, not d3.csv. d3.csv is used for csv files.

```
d3.json("AvgHori.json", function(error, data){
   //code goes here
}),
```